# Jest Next14 useFormState TypeError: (0 , _reactdom.useFormState) is not a function or its return value is not iterable

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, ts-jest, next.js14

While I've tried to test my form component that uses `useFormState` and Next14 Server Actions I get this error `TypeError: (0 , _reactdom.useFormState) is not a function or its return value is not iterable`
I use `react@^18 react-dom@^18 next@14.0.4 @testing-library/jest-dom@^6.1.5 @testing-library/react@^14.1.2 jest@^29.7.0 ts-jest@^29.1.1` 
Here's my component

```
interface Props {
  signInAction: (state: any, formData: FormData) => Promise<any>;
  forgotPasswordAction: (state: any, formData: FormData) => Promise<any>;
}

type SignInError = {
  path: string[];
  message: string;
};

type FormState = {
  auth: boolean;
  errors?: SignInError[];
} | null;

const SignInForm: React.FC<Props> = ({ forgotPasswordAction, signInAction }) => {
  const [signInState, signInFormAction] = useFormState<FormState, any>(
    signInAction,
    null
  );

  const [forgotState, forgotFormAction] = useFormState<FormState, any>(
    forgotPasswordAction,
    null
  );

  let usernameError = signInState?.errors?.find((error) => error.path.includes("username"));
  let passwordError = signInState?.errors?.find((error) => error.path.includes("password"));
  let internalError = signInState?.errors?.find((error) => error.path.includes("internal_error"));
  let emailerror = forgotState?.errors?.find((error) => error.path.includes("email"));

  return (
    <Tabs defaultValue="signin" className="w-full md:w-[500px] lg:w-[900px]" data-testid="teacher-form-tabs">
      <TabsList>
        <TabsTrigger value="signin" data-testid="tab-signin-trigger">
          Sign in
        </TabsTrigger>
        <TabsTrigger value="recovery" data-testid="tab-recovery-trigger">
          Account recovery
        </TabsTrigger>
      </TabsList>
      <TabsContent value="signin">
        <Card>
          <CardHeader>
            <CardTitle>Sign in</CardTitle>
          </CardHeader>
          <CardContent>
            <form action={signInFormAction} className="flex flex-col gap-5">
              <InputGroup
                name="username"
                text="Username"
                type="text"
                error={usernameError?.message}
                testId="username-input"
              />
              <InputGroup
                name="password"
                text="Password"
                type="password"
                error={passwordError?.message}
                testId="passowrd-input"
              />
              <ButtonWithStatus error={signInState?.errors} testId="signin-submit">
                Sign in
              </ButtonWithStatus>
              {internalError && <span className="text-red-500">{internalError.message}</span>}
            </form>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      </TabsContent>
      <TabsContent value="recovery">
        <Card>
          <CardHeader>
            <CardTitle>Forgot password?</CardTitle>
          </CardHeader>
          <CardContent>
            <form action={forgotFormAction} className="flex flex-col gap-5">
              <InputGroup name="email" text="Email" type="email" error={emailerror?.message} />
              <ButtonWithStatus>Send email</ButtonWithStatus>
            </form>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      </TabsContent>
    </Tabs>
  );
};
```

And here's my jest test

```
describe("Sign in form", () => {
  it("renders form", () => {
    render(<SignInForm signInAction={async fnc} forgotPasswordAction{async fnc} />);

    // Get sign in and recovery tab trigger
    let signInTabTrigger = screen.getByTestId("tab-signin-trigger");
    let recoveryTabTrigger = screen.getByTestId("tab-recovery-trigger");

    // Get username input
    let usernameInput = screen.getByTestId("username-input");

    // Get password input
    let passwordInput = screen.getByTestId("password-input");

    // Check if tab triggers are rendered
    expect(signInTabTrigger).toHaveTextContent("Sign in");
    expect(recoveryTabTrigger).toHaveTextContent("Account recovery");

    // Check if username input is rendered
    expect(usernameInput).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(usernameInput).toHaveAttribute("name", "username");

    // Check if password input is rendered
    expect(passwordInput).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(passwordInput).toHaveAttribute("name", "password");
  });
});
```

Am I doing something wrong? It's my first time using Jest.

I've tried setting up mock but with no results.

```
jest.mock("react-dom", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("react-dom"),
  useFormState: () => [() => {}, null],
}));
```

Comment: This might be helpful: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/55919

Answer (score 0):

You might have forgotten to set "use client" at the top, since you're using the 'useFormState' hook within a client component.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm running into the exact same issue for a component that does in fact have the `"use client"` annotation. I don't think it should matter much anyway, since I don't think Jest actually does anything with those annotations.

Comment: I've forgot to add "use client" to the example but I've used it in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem with the test. but i mock hooks in this way:

```
  ...jest.requireActual("react-dom"),
  useFormState: () => [{}, () => {}],
  useFormStatus: () => ({ pending: false }),
}));
```

when i mock both hooks the tests are passed but I'm getting other errors:

````
    Warning: Invalid value for prop `action` on <form> tag. Either remove it from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the DOM. For details, see https://reactjs.org/link/attribute-behavior ```
````